# Como colocar valor da variavel javascript no CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho na página de estilo (css) do site um código para fazer uma animação, mas o tempo da animação deve variar de acordo com uma variável que está no javascript, como faço pra que o valor dessa variável entre no meu código css?

css

```
div.progresso {
    animation: loading "tempo"s ease;
}
```

javascript

```
<script >
    var som1 = document.getElementById("player");
    som1.onloadeddata = function() {
    console.log("tempo:" + player.duration + "segundos");;
    var tempo = player.duration;
    <codigo pra colocar o valor da 'var tempo' naquele lugar especifico do css>
</script>
```

Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Tenta usar a propriedade style: `document.querySelector("div.progresso").style.animation = "loading " + tempo + "s ease"`

Comment: Po funcionou perfeitamente aí sim ein parceiro. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar as variáveis do próprio CSS e atualizar via JavaScript.
Ex.:

Definindo a variável via CSS.

```
:root{
    --tempo-animacao: 1s;
}

div.progresso {
    animation: loading var(--tempo-animacao) ease;
}
```

Atualizando por JS.

```
var root = document.documentElement;

var som1 = document.getElementById("player");
som1.onloadeddata = function() {
   console.log("tempo:" + player.duration + "segundos");;
   var tempo = player.duration;
   root.style.setProperty('--tempo-animacao', tempo);
}
```